# transformation of coordinate systems by rotation

Tags: matrices, transformation

I am trying to convert a set of coordinates from ECEF (Earth Center Earth Fixed) to ENU (East North Up). The operation is performed by applying a rotation matrix as shown in:
[http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geodetic_system#From_ECEF_to_ENU][1]

The article shows that if you have a vector to convert, you apply th e rotation matrix and obtained the desired result as a vector.
My question is: if you apply the same rotation matrix to a matrix of vectors do you have to perform any additional actions, or the multiplication will be sufficient?
I am investigating source code where the conversion is performed like this:

result = RotationMatrix * MatrixToConvert * RotationMatrixTransposed

Does this make sense"?

Isn't in sufficient like this:

result = MatrixToConvert * RotationMatrix

Thank you

Comment: you need to have the RotationMatrix at the left of the MatrixToConvert.$\begin{pmatrix}
\cos(\theta) & -\sin(\theta)\\ 
\sin(\theta) & \cos(\theta)
\end{pmatrix}\cdot\begin{pmatrix}
x_1 & x_2\\ 
y_1 & y_2
\end{pmatrix}$

Comment: But I do not need the transpose of the Rotation Matrix as well. right?

Comment: You can only multiply MatrixToConvert by RotationMatrixTransposed if you have exactly 3 vectors in your matrix of vectors, which doesn't make much sense. I believe you don't need the transposed Matrix